# HTML and CSS3 Selectors

Tags: css

My question relates to another question asked previously - [CSS semantics; selecting elements directly or via order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489452/css-semantics-selecting-elements-directly-or-via-order/15108325#comment21257637_15108325)

Making use of CSS3 selectors tightly couples your CSS to your HTML document. Because of the selector semantics, your CSS becomes reliant on the structure defined within your HTML document. To me this seems very short sighted.

If I understand correctly then this means should the HTML document change, then your styles will no longer apply. Also if you want to reuse that stylesheet somewhere else, you can't.

Can someone with some experience please explain how they deal with these new semantics and provide a real world example?

Comment: CSS isn't *always* about reusability. Also your question needs a better title - it's not related to HTML5 in any way. Look at the question you link to for an example. Also, "schemantics" isn't a real word, although [Urban Dictionary seems to suggest otherwise](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Schemantic).

Comment: The more specific your CSS rules are, it becomes less likely that you can reuse them. In most cases things can be build the same way with HTML, menus etcetera are quite often done the same way.

Comment: @BoltClock could OP be thinking of "semantics"?

Comment: Thanks Allan. Yes I'm thinking semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I didn't communicate my question properly. English isn’t my first language and 'accidents' do happen.

My feeling is when using HTML5/CSS3 that you should avoid using id or class attributes. There are supposedly better ways to go about your business. Then, I wanted to point out that using CSS selectors can make your code brittle and hard to maintain. Perhaps me or you never meant to change the style when you changed from `<p>` to `<span>`.

Either way, I found some interesting approach that I really want to give a try (and share).

Using ARIA you can assign a *role* or *purpose* to your element. In other words you give it context. For instance headers at the top of your page have a different *context\role* to those defined elsewhere such as at the top of an `<article>`. Giving context is exactly what we’re trying to do by using CSS selectors e.g. p.dog (dog in the context of `<p>`).

Here’s a link for those interested on checking it out - [ARIA Landmark Roles](http://adactio.com/journal/4267/)

Answer (score 4):

CSS selectors, done right, *binds* your presentation to the *semantics* of your html page.

If your semantics change, then the CSS selectors are invalid with respect to your page and become unbound.

This is a good thing.

Comment: I agree, if you defined these selectors in the first place.. there probably was a good reason.
Should the HTML change, then the styling should also be different.
If you want a more generic way of CSS, you can still just use classes and id's everywhere.
Depends on 'if', 'where' and 'how' you want to reuse your styling.

Comment: @Alohci. Not exactly sure why you would consider it a good thing. This is exactly why we started using CSS in the first place. Our html used to be tightly coupled with style definitions.

Comment: @Yoeri. It's not just a 'reuse' issue. There is also the 'maintenance' issue - which probably concerns me more. I'm thinking the only solution will be, as you suggest, to use 'id' or 'classes'. Thus <header class="header">

Comment: @Editor CSS is still loosely coupled. I don't see why this is a problem. I really don't see the difference between header{} and .header{}
The only thing I was thinking of is syntax like div>p.

Comment: @Yoeri Absolutely. My point is the example div>p will no longer work if you change <p> to something like <span>. Therefore it is considered 'tightly coupled'.

Again correct, there is no difference between header{} or .header{}. However this would result in code which looks like <header id="header"> or <header class="header">. So my question is - is this what people are doing atm?

Comment: @Editor - And my point is that if your selector says `p.dog` it's because you want that styling to apply to *paragraphs* that have a class of "dog". If, then, you change your `<p>` to a `<span>`, clearly you didn't want the styling to apply any more. If you had wanted the styling to apply to elements of class dog regardless of which element was used, you'd have used a selector of `.dog` rather than `p.dog`.

Comment: @Alohci you may think to object oriented :) . You write classes to use them more then once in your HTML code, thats their job :) . It doesn't matter if it's a `span`- or a `div`-tag, if you want a border and have a `.border` class it fits for both of the tags. Your approach is right for IDs, but CSS classes contain normal properties which can be used for most of the content (such as font, border, color, size, position, ...). If you have unique semantics use an ID instead of classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (for example) [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to specify reusable CSS. With LESS you can define classes

```
.bordered {
  border-top: dotted 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

and use them in any other css

```
#yourId a {
   color: #111;
   .bordered;
}
```

and can do many many more :) .

It's not the holy grail, but it makes the development easier. You can define classes and variables which you can use in almost every future website.

I think there is no generally approach, because every website has it's own colors and styles (border-styles, fonts, ...). So you will always have to change most of your CSS code.

Comment: thanks. I'll check it out but I dont think this is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

This question does not have one exact answer. As many "professionals" apply different approaches it would be extremely hard to generalize. Also the use of selectors may really depend on the case.

I always keep templates (e.g. html and css) that I then reuse a lot ... and of course when reusing stuff you need to fix something, but I dont think I have been ever "screwed" by 1 or 2 from your question =) But i also try to keep the selectors relatively simple and flexible (as a comment on the provided link to the previos question - that is quite an extreme).